# Simple bootstrap-select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-select

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this code.
I'm using jquery 3.3.1
I used bootstrap-select from https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select and copy it to my local to save some load time.
But when I tried to run this, I got this result:

[image: Bootstrap-select .selectpicker not working]

Did I do thing wrong?
I've tried searching for answer, but can't seem to found any working answer. Thanks.

NB: I tried using Chrome and Firefox, both gave me the same result.

Comment: Did you forget to add `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: Do I need to add bootstrap to use bootstrap-select? Sorry, I'm new here at bootstrap-select.

Comment: @StaticBeagle Oh yeah, I need to use bootstrap to use bootstrap-select. Thanks a lot. :) (Just now I tried it)

Comment: You bet. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dependencies section of [this link](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) has your answer.

For this to work, you needs :

- jQuery v1.8.0+
- Bootstrap’s dropdown.js
- Bootstrap's CSS

If you don't have bootstrap in your project, you can add the [minified version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) and customize it for your needs and recompile it.

PS Don't use the bootstrap version 4 because it will probably not work.

Hope it helps !

Comment: any updates on this? It seems this answer still upholds. I am running my project on BS 4.5.2 (JS).

Answer (score 3):

**try this hope it helps** :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to include Bootstrap’s dropdown.js component, and Bootstrap's CSS. Only then you can use `bootstrap-select`. Info is here at the very top http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/.

Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sairam0903/x9bm7qs8/2/

Answer (score 0):

in my case bootstrap is not working, becuase I am using bootstrap 5 and using bootstrap 4 cdns, then I switched it to the bootstrap 5 and worked like a charm. if you want to get 3,4 and 5 bootstrap cdns, you can get these cdns from this video description

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyztNgccjJ8